# Keyboard mappings on laptop seem irreversible

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Laptop with Xubuntu 15.04, Linux 3.19.0-26-generic (x86_64), AT Translated Set 2 keyboard.
I am working with an 105 key keyboard on it, using /settings/keyboard/layout/.

problem: 
when I unplug the external keyboard there is no way to get back to the normal laptop keyboard. Whatever I change in settings, the keyboard map keeps on functioning as type 105. I have tried several laptop layouts without success.

In /settings/keyboard/layout the option selected is "use system defaults". This is the option that works when I start up from a live USB, but that same option does not work in the installed version.

how can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

go to settings/keyboard/behavior and uncheck : Restore num lock state on startup.